# Fix weird shading on quads

Tags: modeling, shaders, topology

My mesh has this strange shading:

[image]

I double checked there is no overlapped vertices. Also the edge flow seems normal:

[image]

It happens even after I triangulate the faces:

[image]

What's happening here?

I tried both Recalculate Normals and Merge by Distance, but nothing changed.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some *Split Normals* have been set to an unusual direction, it happens with imported FBX for example, so go in the *Object Data* panel > *Geometry* and *Clear Custom Split Normals Data*:

[image]